# DevExpress XtraGrid v12.2 GetSelectedRow

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

am using DevExpress v12.2 to develope my C# application ,
so am using GridControl ToolBox ,the problem is  that there is no proprety to get the selectedrow from the GridContol or even his index .
another problem the SelectionChanged Event does not exist too,
The issue is fixed on the v13.2, but i have to  work with the DevExpress v12.2.

I come here cause i didnt find any solution for this after a long research,
Any suggestion please ?

am using this code, its works when i put the index :

```
        Client clients = new Client();
        clients = (Client)gridControl1.MainView.GetRow(0); //0 is the index i put manually 
        MessageBox.Show(clients.ClientNom);
```

So how i get the selectedindex ?, thanks.

Comment: What is your datasource? Table or binding list?

Comment: As far as getting the index use gridControl1.GridView.FocusedRowHandle

Answer (score 1):

I find it,
the solution is to go to the Desginer of the GridControl and select the event,in my case its RowClick,and Handle from there :

```
     private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Client clients = new Client();

        clients = (Client)gridControl1.MainView.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        MessageBox.Show(clients.Email);
    }
```

Thanks for your answer AMR.
Ps : V12.2 of DevExpress GetSelected Rows does not exist like proprety

Answer (score 0):

Happen to be looking at an identical solution to your problem right now.

```
//Get Selected Rows
int[] selectedRows = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GetSelectedRows();

//Get the value of the cell you want. Where GridColumn is your DevXpress GridColumn Object
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GetRowCellValue(selectedRows[0], GridColumn)

//For Entire Row
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.GetRow(selectedRows[0]);
```

(This is in Dev Express v12.1)

Comment: That only give the op one cell value from the row, I believe he wants the whole row as a object.

Comment: Personally I always treat the grid view as a data display device, and always go to the data source to get and changes the data.